# Calling user defined function anywhere? (matlab)

Tags: matlab

Where can i save my document *"function.m"*, so i can call this function from any code in any path of my pc?
I already made some custom functions, but i dont know where to save those codes to be able to call them from any part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save them in a logical place where you can find them back. Then, use [`addpath`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addpath.html) to add that folder to MATLAB's search path, i.e. when you use a function it will try that folder as well to find it.

You can do this either per script, or edit `startup.m` with this, so that it's automatically included when MATLAB starts.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to [Adriaan's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42544138/7649907) best practice answer, the fastest option is to save your `function.m` in the `%USERPROFILE%/Documents/MATLAB` directory on your PC (`$home/Documents/MATLAB` on Linux and Mac). This directory is on your MATLAB Search Path by default. This might be an acceptable solution if you use the function commonly across different projects.

Finally, there is a *"manual"* solution: Execute `pathtool` in MATLAB, add the directory containing your `function.m` via the GUI and hit save.